# How is prestige gain computed when battling a gym you own?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I took over a gym, I wanted to level it up. I battled it with my most powerful Pokemon (who was about twice the CP of the pokemon in the gym) and I gave less prestige when I used a more powerful Pokemon (+100) than when I used one closer to the CP of the gym'd Pokemon (+284).

So, how is prestige gain computed? Prestige loss is fairly static but it's unclear to me what the rate of gain is and what influences it.

Comment: I haven't properly tested this, but it seems to be 500 +/- the CP difference.

Comment: Would defeating a 500 Pokemon with a 1000 Pokemon gain +0 then?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I think theres a minimum. Like i said, i haven't tested of this would be an answer.

Comment: @Studoku it's a percentage of the CP difference, so you can defeat a 20CP magikarp with a 10CP rattata and get +1000 (max) prestige.